How to Fix : "SSIS context menu problem duplicate issue"in Visual Studio"
This happens when I right click on the SSIS package and I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me fix it?
I hope there will be a way to fix it so I don't have to display too many of the same thing on one working window screen
enter image description here
